# loosing session when try to run Karate scripts using Jenkins

Tags: api, karate

I am trying to run Karate scripts using jenkins where I have defined login credentials in Background and in Scenario I am performing Get call when I try to run this script using Karate it Successfully executes. But when I try to run it using jenkins the scenario throwing an error 'Not Permitted'.
I think It is loosing it's session when I try to run it with Jenkins.
Please Help!!

Comment: this is the type of question I personally think no one can help you - you have to figure it out yourself. take the help of some IT or networking folks if needed. maybe your jenkins server does not have network connectivity to your server. maybe you need to configure an HTTP proxy. all the best